Generate a PG dump when click a button
im creating a rails app (basically a monolith). currently, im creating a new feature, "when i click some button, it download a sql script with db backup".
i understand that i can execute this command "PGPASSWORD=password pg_dump -U pguser -h localhost db_name_development > /tmp/backup-test.sql" and i can get the backup, but when i execute the command on the terminal, nothing happends.
Also, i created a controller and a view with the feature, when i click on the download button, my browser downloads the file but instantly throws me an "network error" and stops the download.
is my code bad or something? im still learning.
Controller:
class BackupsController < ApplicationController
  def download
    dump_file = create_backup

    send_file dump_file, type: 'application/sql', disposition: 'attachment', filename: File.basename(dump_file)
  ensure
    File.delete(dump_file) if dump_file && File.exist?(dump_file)
  end

  private

  def create_backup
    timestamp = Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    dump_file = Rails.root.join('tmp', "backup-#{timestamp}.sql")

    db_config = Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    db_username = 'postgres'
    db_password = 'postgres'
    db_name = 'yunex_sicc_development'
    db_host = db_config['host'] || 'localhost'

    command = "PGPASSWORD=#{db_password} pg_dump -F c -v -U #{db_username} -h #{db_host} #{db_name} -f #{dump_file}"

    if system(command)
      dump_file.to_s
    else
      raise "Backup failed"
    end
  end
end

View:
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 text-center">
                <%= link_to(download_backup_path, method: :get, class: 'btn btn-outline-primary py-2 w-100' ) do %>
                    <%= image_tag "adm_icon_download_db.svg", class: "img-fluid img-button" %>
                    download db.
                <% end %>
            </div>

routes.rb:
get 'backups/download', to: 'backups#download', as: 'download_backup'



While I have no idea why you would like such a thing here are some resources to review: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39182424/postgresql-dump-from-ruby-on-rails-controller, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50851924/dump-postgres-db-rails, https://coderwall.com/p/2e088w/rails-rake-tasks-to-dump-restore-postgresql-databases. Sidenote: If you are checking this in to source control I would be extremely concerned about your controller code exposing database credentials.

features that come from people who do not know the dangers of downloading the backup like this, but for now this is just a tests that I do, the data that I have there is not the real one. Thanks for the links, ill check them.

@engineersmnky I have this capability in an app I work on. It has been indispensible to quickly resolve bugs that are data-related. That is, they show up on production data, but the test suite runs fine and my dev environment doesn't replicate the problem. There is a companion capability on my dev app that loads data from the downloaded dump. Of course, security measures are in place.

You don't need to reinvent the wheel. Rails already has a rake task for this. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb#L46
